# Save map so it can be automatically use in by-loops

Tags: r, loops, group-by, maps

I would like to make several species maps. The problem is that when using the `by` command, it has to create the map every time an iteration is made. I would like to know if it is possible to save the map somehow so it can  be used automatically.

I tried with the `recordPlot()` function, but it gives me an error and it generate blank maps:

```
library(raster)

elevation <- getData("alt", country = "ES", mask=F)
slope <- terrain(elevation, opt = "slope",neighbors=4) 
aspect <- terrain(elevation, opt = "aspect",neighbors=4)
hill <- hillShade(slope, aspect, 40, 270)
newextent<-extent(-7.99, -2.87, 39.9, 41.5)
land.pal <- colorRampPalette(c("#336600", "#F3CA89", "#D9A627", 
                               "#A49019", "#9F7B0D", "#996600", 
                               "#B27676", "#C2B0B0", "#E5E5E5", 
                               "#FFFFFF"), space="Lab") (1000)

plot(disaggregate(crop(elevation,newextent), 20, method="bilinear"), col = land.pal, legend=F)  

map <- recordPlot()

by(data, data$Species, FUN = function(data) {
  pdf(file=paste0("map ", data$Species,".pdf"), onefile=F, width=6,height=3, pointsize=1)
  plot.new()
  map  
  points(data$Lat, data$Long, pch=21, bg="black", cex=0.85)
  dev.off()
})
```

Thank you in advance

Data:

```
Lat Long    Species
-6.99   40.49   Sp1
-5.05   40.60   Sp1
-3.30   40.02   Sp1
-7.51   40.86   Sp1
-3.18   40.24   Sp1
-3.83   40.08   Sp1
-7.28   40.91   Sp1
-7.74   40.53   Sp1
-7.72   40.69   Sp1
-4.36   40.06   Sp1
-5.90   40.51   Sp2
-5.56   40.07   Sp2
-3.52   40.19   Sp3
-6.29   40.93   Sp3
-6.77   40.12   Sp3
-7.11   40.77   Sp4
-5.81   40.88   Sp4
-5.27   40.68   Sp4
-6.31   40.34   Sp4
-6.13   40.32   Sp4
-6.73   40.99   Sp4
-5.32   40.71   Sp4
-6.17   40.97   Sp4
-4.77   40.92   Sp4
-6.45   40.58   Sp5
-5.54   40.39   Sp5
-6.56   40.66   Sp5
-5.27   40.37   Sp5
```

Comment: Try replacing the line `map` within your loop with `replayPlot(map)`?

Comment: It worked!! Thank you Z. Lin!